# If $\gcd(a,b)=9,$ then what is $\gcd(a^2,b^3)\,?$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

I know that by the euclidean algorithm, I can obtain the following equations.

I tried some algebraic manipulation but I can't seem to determine, if $$\text{if }\;\gcd(a,b)=9,\text{ then what is }\gcd(a^2,b^3)\;?$$

Comment: Hint: $\;a=9p, b=9q\,$ with $\,\gcd(p,q)=1\,$.

Comment: Could you explain in more detail what have you tried?

Comment: What does "how is $\gcd(a^2,b^3) = ?$" mean.  How do you prove what?  I don't see any statement you are proving.  Are you trying to solve $\gcd(a^2,b^3)$?  Or you trying to prove it has a specific solution?  If so what solution?

Comment: Notice if $a = 27$ and $b = 18$ then $\gcd(a,b) = 9$ and $\gcd(a^2,b^3 ) = \gcd(729, 5832) = 729$ but if $a = 18$ and $b=27$ then $gcd(a,b) = 9$ and $gcd(a^2,b^3) = \gcd(324, 19683) = 81$

Comment: I honestly did not understand what the question was asking.

Comment: Are we sure this is not a duplicate question?

Answer (score 6):

$\gcd(a,b) = 9$.  So $a = 9k$ and $b=9j$ and $k$ and $j$ have no factors in common.

$\gcd(a^2,b^3) = \gcd(9^2k^2, 9^3j^3)$.  $9^2k^2$ and $9j^3$ have $9^2$ in common.

So $\gcd(a^2,b^3) = \gcd(9^2k^2, 9^3j^3) = 9^2*\gcd(k^2, 9j^3)$.  $k, j$ have no factors in common with each other but $9$ and $k^2$ may have factors is common.  If they do then that prime factor in common is $3$ and $9|k^2$.

So

CASE 1:  $a = 9k$ and $b=9j$ and $3|k$. so $k= 3l$ for some $l$ and $a = 27l$.  If so then $3 \not \mid j$ (as $j,k$ have no factors in common).

So $\gcd(a^2, b^3) = \gcd(27^2l^2, 9^3j^3)$.  These have $9^3$ in common but $l$ and $j$ have no factors in common and no power of $3$ divides $j^3$.

So $\gcd (a^2,b^3) = 9^3$.

CASE 2: $a = 9k$ and $b = 9j$ and $3 \not \mid k$.  Then $\gcd(a^2,b^3) = \gcd(9^2k^2, 9^3j^3)$.  These have $9^2$ in common.  $j$ and $k$ have nothing in common and no power of $3$ divides $k^2$.

So $\gcd(a^2,b^3) = 9^2$.

So the $\gcd(a^2,b^3) = 9^3$ if $27|a$ but $\gcd(a^2,b^3) = 9^2$ if $27 \not \mid a$.

Answer (score 4):

Note $\ (A,B) = 9\,\Rightarrow A,B = 9a,9b,\ \color{}{(a,b) = 1},\, $ so $\,\color{#c00}{(a^2,b^3) = 1}\,$ by Euler

Thus  $\ (A^2,B^3) = ((9a)^2,(9b)^3) = 81(\color{#c00}{a^2},9\color{#c00}{b^3}) = 81(a^2,9) = 81(a,3)^2 = (A,27)^2$

Comment: Not right - see @fleablood comment on question.

Comment: @Ethan Did you miss the (upcased)  notation change? The answer agrees with fleablood's examples.

Comment: Yes. Missed that. Sorry.

Comment: Technically correct but a different choice of letters would help clarity.

Comment: @Robert Using different letters obscures the relationship. Some authors use overbars, primes, etc, but I find it clearer to simply alter the case, e.g. lowercasify (as above).

Comment: @Bill And of course it would be petty of me to downvote you over such a trivial detail. After all, some people will have trouble understanding no matter how much effort you put into details like these.

Answer (score 4):

If $\gcd(a, b) = 9$, that means that $a = 9m$, $b = 9n$, and $\gcd(m, n) = 1$.

Just in case you have any doubt on that last point, let's say $k = \gcd(m, n) > 1$. Then $k$ is a divisor of both $a$ and $b$, and in fact $\gcd(a, b) = 9k > 9$. But if $k = \gcd(m, n) = 1$, that preserves $\gcd(a, b) = 9$.

With that out of the way, we can tackle $\gcd(a^2, b^3)$. We see that $a^2 = 81m^2$ and $b^3 = 729n^3$. Since squaring and cubing add no new distinct prime factors, $\gcd(m^2, n^3) = 1$. This problem then boils down to $\gcd(81, 729) = 81$.

Try plugging in some specific values: $\gcd(18, 45) = 9$. Then $\gcd(18^2, 45^3) = \gcd(324, 91125) = 81$.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest trying many cases, with $s,t$ not divisible by $3.$ Figuring out each case should help explain what is going on.

A. $ a = 3^2 s, b = 3^2t.$

B. $a = 3^2 s, b = 3^3 t.$

C. $a = 3^2s, b = 3^4 t.$

D. $ a = 9s, b = 3^5 t. $

### and so on.

BB. $a = 3^3s, b = 3^2t$

CC. $a = 3^4s, b = 3^2t.$

DD. $a = 3^5s, b = 3^2t$

and so on.